# Process huge volume of data using Java

Tags: java, database

As part of the requirement we need to process nearly 3 million records and associate them with a bucket. This association is decided on a set of rules (comprising of 5-15 attributes, with single or range of values and precedence) which derive the bucket for a record.
Sequential processing of such a big number is clearly out of scope.
Can someone guide us on the approach to effectively design a solution?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are looking for a bit more?  I don't see how you can possibly processes the records without iterating through it in some way.  Or are you looking for some multi threaded solutions?

Comment: Are you talking about processing 3 million records once or on a daily/weekyly/monthly basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 million records isn't really that much from a volume-of-data point of view (depending on record size, obviously), so I'd suggest that the easiest thing to try is parallelising the processing across multiple threads (using the java.util.concurrent.Executor framework). As long as you have multiple CPU cores available, you should be able to get near-linear performance increases.

Comment: +1 for "3M records is not a big number". a 3M countdown takes 0.1 seconds on a modern CPU.

Comment: I realize the other things you're getting at in your answer - I also firmly believe that the stance of the OP that 3M records is too many for linear processing when you need to summarize each record anyway is too erroneous for words.

Comment: Linear in this case, of course, meaning that each record needs to be processed, not anything to do with the parallelization possibilities of their rule set.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the data source. If it is a single database, you will spend most of the time retrieving the data anyway. If it is in a local file, then you can partition the data into smaller files or you can pad the records to have equal size - this allows random access to a batch of records.

If you have a multi-core machine, the partitioned data can be processed in parallel. If you determined the record-bucket assignment, you can write back the information into the database using the PreparedStatement's batch capability.

If you have only a single core machine, you can still achieve some performance improvements by designing a data retrieval - data processing - batch writeback separation to take advantage of the pause times of the I/O operations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're after [but here's a blog post about how the New York Times used Apache Hadoop Project to process a large volume of data](http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/11/01/self-service-prorated-super-computing-fun/).

Comment: Hadoop is likely overkill for this. Hadoop's idea of "huge" is rather different to a few million - its intended for terabytes of data. The offort of setting up Hadoop is not to underestimated, as impressive as it is.

Comment: You're right.  I also realised I linked to the wrong post. It's now changed to one that doesn't mention Map/Reduce but is an interesting little story about when Hadoop can be used.  However, the Map/Reduce toolkit mentioned in the other post does apparently make Hadoop easier to use and can be used without it.  That might be relevant here but again probably not.  Anyway, here's that post: http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/05/11/announcing-the-mapreduce-toolkit/

Answer (score 1):

As a meaningless benchmark, we have a system that has a internal cache. We're currently loading 500K rows. For each row we generate statistics, place keys in different caches, etc. Currently this takes < 20s for us to process.

It's a meaningless benchmark, but it is an instance that, depending on the circumstances, 3M rows is not a lot of rows on todays hardware.

That said.

As others have suggested, break the job up in to pieces, and parallelize the runs, 1-2 threads per core. Each thread maintains their own local data structures and state, and at the end, the master process consolidates the results. This is a crude "map/reduce" algorithm. The key here is to ensure that the threads aren't fighting over global resources like global counters, etc. Let the final processing of the thread results deal with those serially.

You can use more than one thread per core if each thread is doing DB IO, since no single thread will be purely CPU bound. Simply run the process several times with different thread counts until it comes out fastest.

We've seen 50% speed ups even when we run batches through a persistent queueing system like JMS to distribute the work vs linear processing, and I've seen these gains on 2 core laptop computers, so there is definite room for progress here.

Another thing if possible is don't do ANY disk IO (save reading the data from the DB) until the very end. At that point you have a lot more opportunity to batch any updates that need to be made so you can, at least, cut down on network round trip times. Even if you had to update every single row, large batches of SQL will still show net gains in performance. Obviously this can be memory intensive. Thankfully, most modern systems have a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you have to use Java to process the data? Couldn't you use SQL queries to write to intermediate fields? You could build upon each field -- attributes -- until you have everything in the bucket you need.

Or you could use a hybrid of SQL and java... Use different procedures to get different "buckets" of information and then send that down one thread path for more detailed processing and another query to get another set of data and send that down a different thread path...

Answer (score 0):

This goes the same for most projects where you need to process large amounts of information. I am going to assume that each record is the same, e.g. you process it the same way each time, which would be the point you can spawn a separate thread to do the processing.

The second obvious point is where you are fetching your information, this case you mentioned a database, but really that is pretty irrelevant. You want to separate your I/O and processing elements in your code to separate threads (or more likely, a pool of executors for the processing).

Try to make each as independent as possible, and remember to use locking when necessary. Here are some links that you may want to read up on.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-thread.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-threads1.html

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Multithreading-in-Java/

Answer (score 0):

Effective design steps for this scenario consist of first, determining any and all places where you can partition the records to be processed to allow full-engine parallelization (i.e., four units running against 750k records each is comparatively cheap). 
Then, depending upon the cost of the rules that summarize your record (I am viewing assignment of a bucket as a summarization operation), determine if your operation is going to be CPU bound or record retrieval bound.

If you're CPU bound, increasing the partitioning is your best performance gain. If you're IO bound, rule processing worker threads that can work in parallel in response to chunked data retrieval is a better-performing design.

All of this assumes that your rules will not result in state which needs to be tracked between records. Such a scenario deeply threatens the parallelization approach. If parallelization is not a tractable solution because of cumulative state being a component of the rule set, then your best solution may in fact be sequential processing of individual records.

Answer (score 0):

> Sequential processing of such a big
>   number is clearly out of scope.

I don't think you know that.  How long does it take to process 1,000 records in this way?  10,000?  100,000?  1,000,000?  If the answer is really "too long," then fine: start to look for optimizations.  But you might find the answer is "insignificant," and then you're done.

Other answers have alluded to this, but it's my entire answer.  Prove that you have a problem before you start optimizing.  Then you've at least got a simple, correct system to profile and against which to compare optimized answers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the revised description, I think I'd try and look at sorting the data.

Sorting can be an n*log(n) process; and if most of the comparisons are for direct equality on sortable fields, this should yield a total complexity of ~O(n*log(n)). Theoretically. If after assigning an item to a bucket it's no longer needed, just remove it from the list of data.

Even if the data needed to be resorted a few times for various steps in the logic, it should still be a bit faster then then n^2 approach.

Basically, this would involve preprocessing the data to make it easier for actual processing.

This makes certain assumptions about the logic of bucket assigning (nameley that it's not too far from the psuedo code provided); and would be invalid if you needed to extract data from every pair of A,B.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I would comment if I could; but, alas, I am too new. Preprocessing applies as much to the data as it does to the individual categories. Ultimately all you need to do to go from a 15 minute compute time to a 5 minute compute time is to be able to programmatically determine 2/3s+ of the categories that cannot and will never match... in less then O(n) amortized time. Which might not be applicable to your specific situation, I admit.

Comment: Sorting can be an n*log(n)
> process; and if most of the
> comparisons are for direct equality on
> sortable fields, this should yield a
> total complexity of O(n*log(n)+n).
> Theoretically. If after assigning an
> item to a bucket it's no longer
> needed, just remove it from the list
> of data No, we can't delete the items after assigning it to a bucket. Its a real data and has to be stored back in the database after processing.
Also, we can't sort the data on some parameter bcoz, both of them are two different entities. Its just that we are trying to relate them thru some parame

Answer (score 0):

I would make efforts to push back with the specification author to focus more on 'what' needs to be done, rather than how.  I can't imagine why a specifcation would push'java' for a data intensive operation.  If it has to do with data, do it with SQL.  If your using Oracle there is a function called nTile.  So creating a fixed set of buckets is as trivial as:

select ntile(4)over(order by empno) grp,
 empno,
 ename
from emp

Which results in:

```
GRP EMPNO ENAME
--- ----- ---------
1  7369 SMITH
1  7499 ALLEN
1  7521 WARD
1  7566 JONES
2  7654 MARTIN
2  7698 BLAKE
2  7782 CLARK
2  7788 SCOTT
3  7839 KING
3  7844 TURNER
3  7876 ADAMS
4  7900 JAMES
4  7902 FORD
4  7934 MILLER
```

At minimum you could at least establish your 'buckets' in SQL, then your Java Code would just need to process a given bucket.

```
Worker worker = new Worker(bucketID);
worker.doWork();
```

If you don't care about the number of buckets (the example above was asking for 4 buckets) tbut rather a fixed size of each bucket (5 records per bucket) then the SQL is:

```
select ceil(row_number()over(order by empno)/5.0) grp,
  empno,
  ename
from emp
```

Output:

```
GRP      EMPNO ENAME
    --- ---------- -------
1       7369 SMITH
1       7499 ALLEN
1       7521 WARD
1       7566 JONES
1       7654 MARTIN
2       7698 BLAKE
2       7782 CLARK
2       7788 SCOTT
2       7839 KING
2       7844 TURNER
3       7876 ADAMS
3       7900 JAMES
3       7902 FORD
3       7934 MILLER
```

Both examples above come from the terrific book:
SQL Cookbook, 1st Edition by Anthony Molinaro